# C++/Arduino Passing pointer to 2D array stored in PROGMEM to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I have several const int 2D arrays globally stored in PROGMEM. for example:

```
const int image1[][17]PROGMEM = {
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
  {1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}
}
```

I would like to read out this 2d image array in a function. Which image to read out should be specified in the argument.

```
void printImage(image)
{
  // do something with element i,j of image
  pgm_read_byte(image[i][j])
}
```

I am not very expierenced with the use of pointers etc. but I know that's the way to do it. Can you show me how to make it work?

How I do it now; I have the function printImage1() without any arguments, and in the body function I use:

```
pgm_read_byte(&image1[i][j])
```

to read out image1. For image2, image3 etc. I copy the function printImage1 and change imgage1 from above to image2, image3 etc. This is redundant programming thats why I want to specify the image in the argumant using only one function printImage.

Comment: Are all your images the same size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easily - by using array reference:

```
void printImage(const int (&image)[5][17])
{
    // ...
}
```

If you want the array being passed to be always with the size of 5 x 17. Else you can use a pointer to it's first element:

```
void printImage(const int (*image)[17])
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it had to do with the & and * but didn't know how.

Comment: It does not work, the compiler says
    error: 'printImage' was not declared in this scope
even though the function is declared as it should. ??

Comment: ok i solved the problem, i had to add an explicit prototype above the setup function
void printImage(const uint8_t (&image)[60][17]);